# Clear echo messages in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I have a text box in which the user can start typing the name of a company and it will start listing the companies to choose from. The problem I am having is that if I click ENTER with empty box it gives the message "Please enter a stock" but then when the user starts typing the previous message stays there and the suggestions are also shown. How do I remove the previous message?
This is the page

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $stock = lookup(strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]));


    if(empty($_POST["symbol"])){

        echo"You must enter a stock symbol";
        exit;

    }else if($_POST["symbol"]){

    $price = number_format($stock['price'], 2);

    echo "A share of {$stock['name']} costs $price";
    }

}

else{

    // render portfolio
render("stock_search.php", ["title" => "Get Quote"]);
}
```

Comment: try outputting error message to a div and clearing it through javascript

Comment: Don't just echo the string, echo into some sort of `<DIV>` or something, then you can select that div with javascript and remove it

Comment: you need to use javascript for that. could be obstructive `<input onfocus="if(this.value=='your default value'){this.value=''}else{this.value='your default value'}" onblur="..." />` or unobstructive which is a longer code, which you can find answer to here on stackoverflow for that. but you probably use some kind of plugin for that, so the documentation is best place to look.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide or clear the suggestions with JavaScript on (re-)start of typing.

Comment: How do I check if the user has restarted typing in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

you suould redirect to page so that the page refreshes and message removes

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

$stock = lookup(strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]));


if(empty($_POST["symbol"])){

    echo"You must enter a stock symbol";
    //use redirect method to move page or refresh the same page not use exit; 

}else if($_POST["symbol"]){

$price = number_format($stock['price'], 2);

echo "A share of {$stock['name']} costs $price";
}

}

else{

    // render portfolio
render("stock_search.php", ["title" => "Get Quote"]);
}
```